# Windows boot problem after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, xubuntu, windows-10

I am installing Ubuntu 20.10 by using "erase disk and install Ubuntu" and using "use LVM partition" in advanced option. Now I want to go back to windows and want to using dual boot. But when I want to install, it always show the error "Reboot and select proper boot device or insert a boot media in selected boot device and press a key..".
I checked my boot option in BIOS and and also checked my hard disk and other connection it only gives the error when I try to install windows.
I tried to install from USB and DVD drive, but nothing changes, help me out how can I recover from this problem?

Comment: No, I only have single hard drive. After "Erasing and install Ubuntu " it turned in a single partion of 999 gb.

Comment: I don't have any windows I want to install it now

Comment: yeah I can boot ubuntu and  can use it

Comment: So you have the Windows 10 installation disk and your problem is getting your system to boot off of it? Do you also still need to partition the disk?